# Subclassing Flask unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with subclassing Flask in my app. I'm getting a unexpected keyword argument exception in my classes init.

app/controller.py

```
from app.searchapi import SearchService

[...]

def main(args, config):
  app = SearchService(someValue=True)
  app.run(threaded=True, use_reloader=False, debug=False,
              host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

app/searchapi.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, make_response, json

class SearchService(Flask):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not args:
            kwargs.setdefault('import_name',__name__)
        self.someValue = kwargs.get('someValue')
        super(SearchService, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.route("/", methods=['GET'])(self.HelloWorld)

    def HelloWorld(self):
        return "Hello, World"
```

Returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/div/Project/app/controller.py", line 158, in main
    app = SearchService(someValue=True)
  File "/Users/div/Project/app/searchapi.py", line 15, in __init__
    super(SearchService, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'someValue'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the `someValue` kwarg to the superclass, Flask, where it's unexpected. Instead of `get`ting it, try this:

```
self.someValue = kwargs.pop('someValue')
```

This removes it from kwargs, and when you pass those to Flask, it's gone.